# How do I generate an output like "1.0 2.0 3.0 4.0 5.0 5.1 5.2 5.3 5.4 5.5" in R?

Tags: r

We are supposed to learn the `seq()`, `:` and `rep()` command with this exercise but I must have missed something. I cant wrap my head around how you can change the output intervals of a sequence mid sequence like that.

Like the title says the desired output is `1.0 2.0 3.0 4.0 5.0 5.1 5.2 5.3 5.4 5.5`.

I've tried chaining commands like this but it resulted in the below output:

```
1:5 ; seq(from = 5.1, to = 5.5, by = 0.1)
```

But it resulted in this output

```
[1] 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 
[1] 5.1, 5.2, 5.3, 5.4, 5.5
```

I also tried assigning the output of those two commands to variables but I don't quite know how to combine them without adding the values together.

Many thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

You could do

```
c(1.0:5.0, seq(5.1,5.5,.1))
```

**output**

```
 [1] 1.0 2.0 3.0 4.0 5.0 5.1 5.2 5.3 5.4 5.5
```

Answer (score 1):

I guess your code should be `c(seq(1,5,1), seq(5.1, 5.5,0.1))`

then you have a single vector with the desired output